# What would happen if neutron beam hits a neutron star?

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutron-stars

Suppose there is a continuous stream of neutrons constantly hitting a neutron star, does it adds to the mass but do the surface of the neutron star still remains fairly even? How about nuclear fusion but neutron star is already saturated with neutron already.

Comment: Neutron stars are not made just out of neutrons. In particular the surface is normal matter (very hot normal matter :-).

Comment: This is an undefined problem. It will depend on the energy of the beam, the particular surface of the particular neutron star etc. Inn general it will depend on the scattering crossection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each neutron that hits the neutron star will increase the (conserved) baryon number of the neutron star by 1.

Free neutrons are unstable in the outer crust of a neutron star, so will decay into protons and electrons on a ten minute timescale.

Those that are absorbed into the increasingly neutron-rich nuclei will just participate in the general equilibrium reactions that are already going on in the crust.

Nothing dramatic happens unless you significantly increase the mass of the neutron star, thus causing structural changes.

Comment: If the NS is pretty heavy, such as with the photon sphere, chances are that most protons and electrons emitted by the neutron decay in the crust would not escape the gravity, but return. Would they recombine back into neutrons? If so, then the NS should be a source of emission of the equal number neutrinos and anti-neutrinos. Is this correct and by any chance has this been observed? Finally, isn't a NS covered by a thin layer of iron (which may prevent the neutron decay in the crust)?

Comment: @safesphere Why would iron prevent neutron decay? Free neutrons are not stable until densities reach $3\times 10^{14}$ kg/m$^3$, about 1km below the surface. Young neutron stars should be strong neutrino emitters. It has not been observed. Free protons (hydrogen nuclei) and electrons should exist at the surface of a neutron star.

Comment: I get it, thanks. This condition sounds like a long term balance meaning that the rate of the neutron decay must be equal the rate of neutron production from protons and electrons. Otherwise the NS would eventually decay, which is not the case. This implies the equal number of neutrinos and anti-neutrinos and the constant energy loss. Is my thinking correct?